# How exactly works this Node.js exports\require staatements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am pretty new in nodeJS and JS technologies in general (I came from Java).
I am working on the following simple code and I have the following doubt about how this **require** statement actually works:

I have this file containing some **mocha** test code:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');       // It is a constructor

const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

const { interface, bytecode } = require('../compile');

let accounts;
let inbox;


beforeEach(async () => {
    // Get a list of all accounts:
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()         // use the web3 module to interact with ETH cryupto
       
    // Use one of these accounts to deploy the contract:
    inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
                    .deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: ['Hi there!'] })
                    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' })
});

describe('Inbox', () => {
    it('depploys a contract', () => {
        console.log(accounts);
        console.log(inbox);
    });
});
```

As you can see I have this line:

```
const { interface, bytecode } = require('../compile');
```

from what I can understand it is creating a JS object (please, correct me if I am doing wrong assertion) containing two fields retrieved by the **../compile** "module" (in it **compile** a module?)

And here I have the following doubts: I suppose that it is related to the **compile.js** file that I have into the parent folder (parent related to the mocha script folder). This **compile.js** folder contains the following code:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf-8');


console.log(solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':Inbox']);    
module.exports = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':Inbox'];
```

The only thing that I can think is that this **solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':Inbox']** is an object containing some fields including these **interface** and **bytcode** fields.

So if I well understood it should works in this way:

- The **compile.js** file exports (so it means that make available to the outside world) the entire object represented by **solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':Inbox']**.
- then into the **Inbox.test.js** file it does:

  ```
   const { interface, bytecode } = require('../compile');
  ```

But what exactly means this user of the **require()** statment? It means: take what was exported by the **compile.js** file? If so what is exported is a JavaScript object containing these **interface** and **bytcode** fields that are set as const.

Is it correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you would be correct. It returns whatever `module.exports` is defined as, which you can assign just as you would any variable. By default it is `{}`, an empty object. But if I wanted to export a function, I would do this:

```js
module.exports.myFunc = function(a){
  console.log(a);
}
```

Now `module.exports` has the value `{myFunc: Function()}`. So when I import the module from another file:

```js
const myFile = require('./myFile');
myFile.myFunc("Hello there!"); //Prints: Hello there!
```

When you get a function by name within curly braces, you're *destructuring* the object, take a look at the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). So when you have `const { interface, bytecode } = require("../compile");` you're getting the `interface` and `bytecode` properties of the `compile` module. So you would be correct, that:

`solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':Inbox'];`

has fields which include `interface` and `bytecode`.

```js
{
  interface: Function(),
  bytecode: Function()
}
```

If you import without destructuring the require statement, you could refer to its properties as any other object.

```js
const compile = require("../compile");
compile.interface();
compile.bytecode();
```

You can set `module.exports` to anything, a string, a class, a function. For instance if you exported a string in `myFile.js` as such: `module.exports = "foobar";`, and you imported the file:

```js
const myFile = require("./myFile");
console.log(myFile); //Prints: foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read the documentation for CommonJS modules:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/modules.html

It lays out for you what `require()` does.